Horror movie - trapped in vacant hospital, time behaves oddly
I watched this horror movie about 4 years ago. It was about a bunch of people trapped in a vacant hospital full of scary creatures. These creatures just wanted to kill them for no good reason. I actually remember a scene where one of the characters were killed by one of these creatures when it took his heart (or maybe stomach!) out of his body.
I also remember something was wrong with time in this movie; it was like time was stopped or was reversing, I don't remember exactly.
In another scene a nurse tried to contact other probable people in the hospital by a built-in communication system, which didn't work. A few minutes later, when she was in a different floor and section of hospital, she heard her own voice from the communication system; the same things she spoke earlier. As I mentioned, it was like time was reversing.
That's all I remember. I've tried hard to find this movie ever since, but no luck yet. Hope someone can help me remember the name!

Possibly Dark Floors from 2008 (trailer). Similarities: A bunch of people (including a nurse) stuck in an empty hospital are chased by monsters (played by the band Lordi) and there's a scene where one of the monsters rips out a guy's internal organ in this video around 1:37.

It might be Grave Encounters. It's about a group of people working for a TV show and they decide to visit an abandoned mental hospital at night that is supposedly haunted and the entities or monsters kill them off one by one. YouTube has a trailer for it here.
